# GWT Eclipse Plugin installation: No repository found

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

I was having problems with GWT designer tool. So, I removed the entire GWT plugins. Now, I get many "No Repository found" errors on many of the GWT plugis:

No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,23.0.4.1468518
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,23.0.4.1468518
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,23.0.4.1468518

and many more.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you messed your environment. Just reinstall eclipse completely, and then install GWT plugin in fresh IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that soon. just one more observation: i can install from zip files. Installation goes fine. Plugin appears on the list of plugins. However, Google does not appear in Windows Preferences.

Comment: You may be doing something wrong. Try to install it directly from eclipse as described here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

Comment: Re-installed Eclipse and installed GWT. I still can't see Google in Window/Preferences?

Comment: Do you see blue round (g) tool button?

Comment: No. It does't show it.